# How to fill two empty lists with arcpy.da.SearchCursor and display their differences?

Tags: python, arcpy

As mentioned above, I am currently trying to fill two empty lists with attributes that I get of a geodatabasefile. The attribute's names are 'OBJECTID' and 'COUNTY_NAM' (which stands for county name).
I try to fill the two empty lists with the values that are deposited in those two feature classes of quite similar fgdb. After that, I need to detect the differences between these.

I get this error code `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`
for following code:

```py
import arcpy

#input feature class
fc1 = root1 #can't publish actual root
#target feature class
fc2 = root2 #can't publish actual root

#create empty lists
fc1_list = []
fc2_list = []

#fill with attributes
fields = ['OBJECTID', 'COUNTY_NAM']

#fill first table with searchcursor
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc1, fields) as search_cursor1:
    for row in search_cursor1:
        fc1_list.append([row[0], row[1]])

#fill second table with searchcursor
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc2, fields) as search_cursor2:
    for row in search_cursor2:
        fc2_list.append([row[0], row[1]])

set_list1 = set(fc1_list)
set_list2 = set(fc2_list)

differences = set_list1.difference(set_list2)

print(differences)
```

Answer (score 1):

You get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` because a list is *not* immutable and therefore unhashable.

> Hashable is a feature of Python objects that determines whether the object has a hash value or not. An object is hashable if it has a hash value that doesn't change during its lifetime. A hashable object can be used as a key for a dictionary or as an element in a set.

https://rollbar.com/blog/handling-unhashable-type-list-exceptions

You could use a [tuple](https://realpython.com/python-lists-tuples/#python-tuples) when adding to `fc1_list` instead of a list.

- `(row[0], row[1])` instead of `[row[0], row[1]]`

```py
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc1, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        fc1_list.append((row[0], row[1]))

        # or create a tuple directly from row: 
        # fc1_list.add(tuple(row))
```

---

However, I don't understand why you would use `OBJECTID`. The value of this column is usually an auto-generated value.

> This ID is managed by ESRI software cannot be changed manually. [...] 
> Data conversion causes the ObjectID to be rewritten.

https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000010834

With other words: You have no influence whether both feature class' records have the same `OBJECTID` for the same feature.

---

Here is a working example using some modified data from [Natural Earth (Admin 0 – Countries)](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/). Please note there is one other change I made:

- the tuple is added to the set directly

```py
import arcpy

FIELDS = ["NAME", "NAME_DE"]

fc1 = r"C:\temp\data\countries.shp"
fc2 = r"C:\temp\data\countries_without_switzerland.shp"

records_fc1 = set()
records_fc2 = set()

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc1, FIELDS) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        records_fc1.add(tuple(row))

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc2, FIELDS) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        records_fc2.add(tuple(row))

differences = records_fc1.difference(records_fc2)

print(differences)  # {('Switzerland', 'Schweiz')}
```

---

If you need the values that occur in one of the sets but not in both, then you can also use the XOR operator (`^`).

```py
import arcpy

FIELDS = ["NAME", "NAME_DE"]

fc1 = r"C:\temp\data\countries_without_germany.shp"
fc2 = r"C:\temp\data\countries_without_switzerland.shp"

records_fc1 = set()
records_fc2 = set()

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc1, FIELDS) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        records_fc1.add(tuple(row))

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc2, FIELDS) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        records_fc2.add(tuple(row))

differences = records_fc1 ^ records_fc2

print(differences)  # {('Germany', 'Deutschland'), ('Switzerland', 'Schweiz')}
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Your solution solved the TypeError problem since using tuples instead of lists.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I found a solution that supports the use of lists:
Note: You have to compare list A to list B and the other way round to be able to detect and print all differences between them.

```
import arcpy

#input feature class
fc1 = r"C:\Users\Desktop\ESRI_Training\GISBasics\Arkansas\Arkansas.gdb\Places_Library_Needs"
#target feature class
fc2 = r"C:\Users\Desktop\ESRI_Training\GISBasics_edited_copy\Arkansas\Arkansas.gdb\Places_Library_Needs_edit"

#create empty lists
fc1_list = []
fc2_list = []

#fill with attributes
fields = ['OBJECTID', 'COUNTY_NAM']

#searchcursor for first list
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc1, fields) as search_cursor1:
    for row in search_cursor1:
        #print(u'OBJECTID: %s, County Name: %s' %(row[0], row[1]))
        fc1_list.append(str(row[0]) + ',' + str(row[1]))

#searchcursor for second list
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc2, fields) as search_cursor2:
    for row in search_cursor2:
        #print(u'OBJECTID: %s, County Name: %s' %(row[0], row[1]))
        fc2_list.append(str(row[0]) + ',' + str(row[1]))

#create sets from lists
set_list1 = set(fc1_list)
set_list2 = set(fc2_list)

#you need to look for differences twice, so you have results for each intersection
differences_A = set_list1.difference(set_list2)
differences_B = set_list2.difference(set_list1)

print(differences_A)
print(differences_B)
```

Comment: A string is immutable therefore your solution works. :) If you want the values that occur in one of the sets but not in both, then you can also use the XOR operator (^). I have added a section to my answer.

Comment: I upvoted you Thomas - well deserved - but unfortunately I need at least 15 reputation first. The message though says that the upvote is recorded.